# SDL2 linux fullscreen issue at lower-than-desktop resolution

Tags: graphics, sdl2, linux, fullscreen

Having a problem trying to get proper fullscreen in linux.

I'm using *1440x900* on desktop. When i set SDL to use 1280x720 as fullscreen, it *does* change screen resolution. *But if i drag the mouse cursor to the bottom or right edge of the game screen, it "scrolls" the screen beyond the game surface and makes part of the desktop visible.*

Here's how I set the window/screen:

```
gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, screenWidth, screenHeight,  
SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS ); }
```

- Am i missing some flag(s) perhaps?
- Is this a common problem? I'm on Linux Mint **MATE** (Rosa).
- This problem also occurs when trying to run the same build in an *Openbox* session.
- Using nVidia drivers (x64, v340.96) from nvidia.com, on 9600 GT card(s). No twin/dual screen or second Workspaces.

Any good tips on how to avoid or workaround this issue?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with MATE, I don't get this issue with GNOME, i3, or xmonad.

Comment: Have you tried testing this issue with other desktops or window managers?

Comment: Same problem occurred using Openbox. I will try some others this evening. Though i'm guessing i'd then have to look at workarounds. What SDL version you use btw? (i'm using sdl2-dev from repos).

Comment: Version of libsdl2-dev used is: 2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1 , so ill try to step up from that and see as well.

Comment: I'm using SDL 2.0.4-2 from the Arch Linux official packages.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use `SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS` as fullscreen and borderless are two completely different modes. This might be your problem.

Comment: @tkausl even with BORDERLESS removed, the same thing happens; but then also the 1-2 top pixel lines of the screen is showing from the window's titlebar border. (but no more than that).

Comment: the flag SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED kept it from scrolling outside. Still not sure if that is the correct way or even a solution at all, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag called [SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags) **seems** to prevent the problem from happening. But still not sure if that is the, or a, correct solution.

```
SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, screenWidth, screenHeight, 
SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED );
```